# Автоматическая проверка пароля пользователя в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, bash

Пользователь вводит логин и пароль в консоль программы, есть ли возможность проверить из верность используя с++ linux api или bash?
В моей же ситуации предпологается что в ПО уже зашит пароль и ничего вводить не требуется. (знаю что так не надо делать с точки зрения ИБ, но мне так проще Вам объяснить)

Данный вопрос связан с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-linux)

Comment: Не стоит плодить одинаковые вопросы...

Comment: @Harry Этот вопрос немного отличается. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017397/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-linux#comment1728609_1017408

Comment: 1. «Пользователь вводит». 2. «ничего вводить не требуется». 3. зачем же вводит, если не требуется вводить?

Comment: @НиколаКривошея Думаю стоит отредактировать вопрос, чтобы не было путаницы.

Comment: Brute force что-ли?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить логин и пароль пользователя в linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017397/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, вам поможет [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11031650/1597497) с англоязычного StackOverflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <security/pam_appl.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  

struct pam_response *reply;  

// //function used to get user input  
int function_conversation(int num_msg, const struct pam_message **msg, struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr)  
{  
    *resp = reply;  
        return PAM_SUCCESS;  
}  

int authenticate_system(const char *username, const char *password)   
{  
    const struct pam_conv local_conversation = { function_conversation, NULL };  
    pam_handle_t *local_auth_handle = NULL; // this gets set by pam_start  

    int retval;  
    retval = pam_start("su", username, &local_conversation, &local_auth_handle);  

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
    {  
            printf("pam_start returned: %d\n ", retval);  
            return 0;  
    }  

    reply = (struct pam_response *)malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));  

    reply[0].resp = strdup(password);  
    reply[0].resp_retcode = 0;  
    retval = pam_authenticate(local_auth_handle, 0);  

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
    {  
            if (retval == PAM_AUTH_ERR)  
            {  
                    printf("Authentication failure.\n");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                printf("pam_authenticate returned %d\n", retval);  
            }  
            return 0;  
    }  

    printf("Authenticated.\n");  
    retval = pam_end(local_auth_handle, retval);  

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
    {  
            printf("pam_end returned\n");  
            return 0;  
    }  

    return 1;  
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    char* login;  
    char* password;  

    printf("Authentication module\n");  

    if (argc != 3)  
    {  
        printf("Invalid count of arguments %d.\n", argc);  
        printf("./authModule <username> <password>");  
        return 1;  
    }  

    login = argv[1];  
    password = argv[2];  

    if (authenticate_system(login, password) == 1)  
    {  
        printf("Authenticate with %s - %s through system\n", login, password);  
        return 0;  
    }     

    printf("Authentication failed!\n");  
    return 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в [документации](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html) есть способ получше, но первое что бросается в глаза при беглом просмотре это *item_type* `PAM_TTY` в функции [pam_set_item()](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface-by-app-expected.html#adg-pam_set_item).

Очевидно, что вы можете сделать псевдотерминал (pty) и "скормить" через него пароль модулю аутентификации (т.е. смоделируете ввод пользователя с терминала).